# Convert a string to literal type

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, string-literals

Can somebody help me how  can I convert a bytes string to a literal type, for example:

```
string = 'z\xff\xcaQ\x01\x9b\xe1\xe4\x85\xe4\x1c\xbb\x18yQf\xb0A\x89\xac\x89\x01I\xe2\xec\x06|\x1f\xcf9"\xcf'
```

I want this string to be literal, then I have a function that converts it to  bytes:

```
literal_of_the_string = 'z\xff\xcaQ\x01\x9b\xe1\xe4\x85\xe4\x1c\xbb\x18yQf\xb0A\x89\xac\x89\x01I\xe2\xec\x06|\x1f\xcf9"\xcf'

bytes_of_literal = b 'z\xff\xcaQ\x01\x9b\xe1\xe4\x85\xe4\x1c\xbb\x18yQf\xb0A\x89\xac\x89\x01I\xe2\xec\x06|\x1f\xcf9"\xcf'
```

I tried with this:

```
import struct

def convert_string_to_bytes(string):

    bytes = b''
    for i in string:
        bytes += struct.pack("B", ord(i))
    return bytes
```

But the input must be literal to give me the right answer, I want answer like this:

```
bytes_of_literal = b 'z\xff\xcaQ\x01\x9b\xe1\xe4\x85\xe4\x1c\xbb\x18yQf\xb0A\x89\xac\x89\x01I\xe2\xec\x06|\x1f\xcf9"\xcf'
```

but if I place the string for input, it will be something like this that is not the answer I need:

```
bad_answer =  b'I\\\x1f\\\xf6e5>\\\x8f\\\x04\\\x87\\\xc2[\\\x96\\\x18\\\x7fs\\\xa5'
```

The problem is the string is a variable in a program that I can't put "r" before string. How can I do this?

Comment: Use the `repr()` function to see the literal that you would have to type.

Comment: I'm not following. I ran your code, and `convert_string_to_bytes(string) == bytes_of_literal`. Is that not what you wanted? Or is there a step you're leaving out? Please provide a [mre]. You can [edit].

Comment: Although, the line with `bytes_of_literal` has a syntax error `b '`, that I fixed without realizing.

Comment: Sidenote: `bytes` is a bad variable name since it [shadows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing) the [builtin `bytes` type](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes). You could use something like `b` or `bytes_` instead.

Comment: Another sidenote: You don't even need `struct` for this. `def convert_string_to_bytes(string): return bytes(ord(c) for c in string)`